# Plugin for debugging c/c++/fortran in Vim

Tags: ide

I was wondering if anyone know a good (modern) plugin, similar to [vdebug](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug), that gives a debugging interface for C/C++/Fortran in Vim.

I know about clewn and pyclewn, however, I find these are too bulky and I would much prefer a more simple solution. My thought was that in light of the recent increase in plugin development for Vim, there might be something new that I was not aware of and that provides a more modern interface with fewer dependencies.

Comment: What features are you looking for? For those users who have never used `vdebug`?

Comment: I am looking for features like setting breakpoints and printing value of variable under cursor. In many ways, clewn and pyclewn are both very good alternatives, except I don't want to have to start the debug session separately from my editing session.

Comment: See http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2046/how-can-i-integrate-gdb-with-vim?rq=1 for some possible answers

Comment: Thanks, @michaelavila, I think ConqueGDB seems interesting.