# Is there an upgraded version of the Conque plugin?

Tags: terminal, plugin-conque

My searches for plugins which enable a terminal inside a Vim windows indicate that the main one is [Conque](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Conque-Shell), but the last update was 6 years ago. Are there some other better updated forks which are seen as the goto version?

Are there any newer alternatives to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Conque's description states that:

> ...In other words it is a terminal emulator which uses a Vim buffer to display the program output.

[Neovim](https://neovim.io/) with its [built-in terminal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZbMVj9XSUo) might be your best bet. Once in the terminal buffer, you can press `<c-\><c-n>` to "exit" the insert mode of the terminal and then edit the text as a normal buffer (searching, marks, registers, motions, visual-selection etc).

Answer (score 5):

`vim 8` now also supports `terminal` feature. It also supports to edit terminal buffer as text using `<c-\><c-n>` or `<c-w> + N`, which is called `Terminal-Normal` mode in `vim 8`.

`vim 8` also supports `termdebug`, a plugin that can launch `gdb` with or without builtin `terminal` support.

Just type `packadd termdebug` and `termdebug program_name`, then the current buffer (if not modified) will become source of the program, another 2 split windows for `gdb` and program (in another `tty`).

This provides all functionalities `conque_gdb` provides. For more info about this plugin, type `:h termdebug` after `packadd termdebug`.