# How to copy file and line info from vim to gdb?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, terminal

For setting breakpoints, I was wondering if there is any way to copy the location of a line in a file opened in vim, to gdb rather than typing the whole file path and linenumber in the gdb shell?

Comment: If you're using `tmux` I can give you an easy answer.

Comment: Yes I am using tmux @B Layer.

Comment: Cool. Writing an answer now.

Comment: Alternatively use one of those [external command - How can I integrate gdb with Vim? - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2046/how-can-i-integrate-gdb-with-vim) to eliminate the need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good, since you're using `tmux` then you can use `send-keys` (alias: `send`), a tmux command for inputting text into a different pane than the current one. You can call it from Vim using whatever data you need from there. For current (full) path and line number that would be `expand('%:p')` and `line('.')`

The following command will send those two strings (separated by `:`) to the terminal in pane 3. The combined string will not be submitted (i.e. carriage return is not sent).

```
:exe "!tmux send -t 3 '" . expand("%:p") . ":" . line(".") . "'"
```

So with, for example, a file */tmp/foo.txt* and line number 33 the tmux command that will be executed from the shell is:

```
tmux send -t 3 '/tmp/foo.txt:33'
```

If you want to submit the sent string in the target pane (i.e. by sending a carriage return) you just need to replace the last `"'"` with `"' Enter"`.

Regarding the `-t` param to `send-keys`:

- In its simplest form, takes the target pane index as argument.
- If you are sending your command to another pane in the same window that's the only form we need to know. (Otherwise read the man page and/or ask me.)
- You can display pane indexes in the current window with *tmux-prefix* + `q`.

Obviously, if you're going to use this a lot you'll want to put it in a mapping and/or function. A mapping-only solution:

```
nnoremap XX :<C-U>exe "!tmux send -t " . v:count . " '" . expand("%:p") . " " . line(".") . "'"<CR>
```

Replace `XX` with whatever unused key or key combo you want. Determine the target pane index (used by `-t`) and, from Normal mode, type that number and then your `XX` replacement.

Though a little hard to read, the RHS of this isn't much more than the original `exe` command plus:

- Insertion of the variable `v:count` where the `-t` value goes. `v:count` is a built-in variable that contains any number entered right before entering command-line mode (here that means the number entered before the the mapped key(s) are pressed).
- `<C-U>` triggers Ctrl-U in order to clear the command line before we populate it. (Because when a number is entered right before entering command-line mode (`:`) the command-line is prepopulated with a line range and we don't want that here.)

Alternatively, you could prompt the user for a pane index with a function+mapping. Something like:

```
func! BufferInfoToPane()
    let l:pidx = ...prompt code here...
    exe "!tmux send -t ".l:pidx." '".expand("%:p")." ".line(".")."'"<CR>
endfunc
```

With the mapping:

```
nnoremap XX :call BufferInfoToPane()<CR>
```

Comment: How to create a mapping for this? Also I have one more question, while making a mapping how can I make sure that I am not overwriting any existing mapping?

Comment: Added a mapping. As for overwriting mappings you need to check manually whether something is mapped. `:nmap <leader>X` for normal mode mapping using "\X", for example (assuming default `<leader>` key).

Comment: @ln78 Does it work for you?

Comment: I'll take that as a yes. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found one way which is to use the : terminal feature of vim to start a new shell, run gdb in it and paste the filename from the alternate register #.